# How to enable two angular app running on single hosting machine using NGINX

Tags: angular, ubuntu, nginx

I am using Ubuntu based hosting server to run two different angular apps
respectively running on ports 4200, 4201.

below is my nginx conf file

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name 12.123.125.1;

    location / {
        root /var/www/ng-modern-portal;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /app/ {
        root /var/www/modern-app-ui;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

with this configuration it is working only first routing mappings.
and for `http://12.123.125.1/app` gives me 404 error.

then I tried with keeping one by one only single entries, it is working, but the problem is keeping both of them together.

I tried even separate out location into two different server blocks in nginx conf, but then it gives me conflict in server name. tried with multiple combinations of conf but still nothing is cracked yet.

For e.g. below works
for App-1

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name 12.123.125.1;

    location / {
        root /var/www/ng-modern-portal; # Correct path to your app's build files
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

for App-2

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name 12.123.125.1;

    location /app/ {
        root /var/www/modern-app-ui;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

above individual applying nginx conf works for me, but thats not my goal, wanted to keep both routings.

I appreciate for help, I am not getting whats missing a configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Your Nginx configuration is almost correct, but the issue is likely because of how the root directive works in Nginx. When you use root in a location block, Nginx appends the URI to the root, so your root /var/www/modern-app-ui; would become /var/www/modern-app-ui/app/, which is not what you want.

One solution to this problem is to use the alias directive instead of root for the second location block. Try this:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name 12.123.125.1;

    location / {
        root /var/www/ng-modern-portal;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /app/ {
        alias /var/www/modern-app-ui/;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick help @ben yee, it was a really one line which bothered me a lot.

Comment: the only problem now I am facing is on browser refresh it is giving me `404 ERROR`, other than things are good for me. this happens when I am in `http://12.123.125.1/app/` i.e. in second app